# Changing values of struct in another class

Tags: c#, winforms, struct

While using Winform, I had defined a struct in a main GUI class and change the value of struct in another class. So this is my `Program.cs`:

```
static class Program {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new App());
    }
}

public struct StructExample {
    public string str1;
    public string str2;
}
```

and the codes for main GUI looks like:

```
 public partial class App : Form {

    public StructExample Example = new StructExample();

    public App() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ButtonToClick.Click += (s, evt) => {
            AnotherGUI setWindow = new AnotherGUI(Example);
            setWindow.ShowDialog();
        };
    }
}
```

and the codes for `AnotherGUI` looks like:

```
 public partial class AnotherGUI : Form {
    public StructExample Example;

    public SettingsGUI(StructExample Example) {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Example = Example;
    }

    private void DoSomething() {
        //Change values in Example
        Close();
    }
}
```

But I have a problem that after closing `AnotherGUI`, the values of `Example` wouldn't change. What should I do to change the values of `Example` in `AnotherGUI` to use in `App`?

Comment: Why are you working with mutable structs at all. Nothing in your code shows you can't use classes.

Answer (score 0):

Struct is a value type so you will need to explicitly pass by ref in case you need the receiving method to modify it.

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var example = new Example() { Name = "Name"};
            Console.WriteLine(example.Name);

            WrongStructModifier(example);
            Console.WriteLine(example.Name);

            CorrectStructModifier2(ref example);
            Console.WriteLine(example.Name);
        }

        static void WrongStructModifier(Example example)
        {
            example.Name = "Modified Name";
        }

        static void CorrectStructModifier2(ref Example example)
        {
            example.Name = "Modified Name";
        }
    }

    struct Example
    {
        public string Name;
    }
```

Comment: Ahh... this code itself worked very well, but it didn't work when applied to my  program. I'd rather use class instead